# Как вывести все посты в виджете?

Tags: wordpress

Делаю плагин с виджетом, который отображает записи из постайпа

```
add_action('widgets_init', 'ab_cars_widget');

function ab_cars_widget () {
    register_widget('AB_cars');
}

class AB_cars extends WP_Widget {
        public function widget($args, $instance) {

    $posts_cars = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'cars',
            'numberposts' => $instance['count'],
        )
    );
}
```

Мне нужно вывести ВСЕ записи для использования (10, 20, 30 ...). Но $posts_cars  почему-то содержит только 10 записей. Как мне в $posts_cars передать все записи?
var_dump($instance) выводит массив, где ['count'] пустое значение "". Как мне вывести все посты в виджете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 - это стандартное количество выводимых постов, установленное в админке, на странице Чтение.

Вам надо задать

```
'numberposts' => - 1;
```

Comment: 'numberposts' => $instance['count'], оно отдает пустое значение, я ставил цифру 100, тогда выводились ВСЕ посты, а не 10, как выставляется в админке. -1 интересно...я такого еще не встречал, сейчас попробую

Comment: Я вам советую - читате документацию. https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query